# CMake with SDL 2.0 and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I'm having some trouble compiling a C++11/SDL 2.0 code with CMake. The CMakeLists is pretty simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Test)

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_search_module(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(sdl2test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

add_definitions(-std=c++0x)
add_executable(Test src/main.cpp)
```

However, when compiling, i receive this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target Test
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/var/dev/cmake/src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/var/dev/cmake/src/main.cpp:11:16: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/var/dev/cmake/src/main.cpp:17:16: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

cmake version 2.8.9 and gcc 4.7.2. Any ideas on how to properly make usage of C++11 features with CMake?

ps: I have also tried -std=c++11

Comment: Can you please add the output of `make VERBOSE=1`. I suppose that the definition is not added.
Actually, -st=c++11 is not a flag but part of the compiler. For me `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 ")` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`add_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_definitions) is really for setting preprocessor definitions. You need to set the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` here:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Comment: You removed the `add_definitions` call I assume?  Can you run `make VERBOSE=1` and paste the output please?

Comment: Can you try from scratch in a clean build folder?  The `set` command is definitely correct; I use this frequently.

Comment: I just checked, and your original `add_definitions(-std=c++0x)` should actually also work, even though it's not a preprocessor definition.

Comment: You can check the flag is passed using [this minimal example](http://pastebin.com/YhJcwRMv).  Just copy the CMakeLists.txt to a folder, `cd` to that folder then run [these commands](http://pastebin.com/Pz7Qv4pi)

Comment: Possibly, but I can't see anything in your example CMakeLists.txt which would cause the value of the CXX flags to be reset/changed.  The `pkg_search_module` should really only set variables like `SDL2_CFLAGS` and shouldn't touch `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.  Possibly setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` early in the CMakeLists.txt and then immediately after putting `variable_watch(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)` is the best way to debug this.